# The remote server returned an error: NotFound. From Windows Phone Simulator when doing HTTP Post request With HttpWebRequest

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, azure-storage

OK. Been using this code for a while now but all of a sudden today it started giving me the "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." error.

My Blob Storage container is configured to be 'Public read access (blobs only)'. 
'
I can access the file from internet explorer on my desktop perfectly.

I get an Internal Server error 500 when I access from Internet Explorer within the WP7 simulator.
Inside my app, my WebClient downloadstringAsync gives me 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound.'

Not really sure what's going on but it seems my WP7 simulator's networking is screwed up.

**Update:** Rebooted. Ran DSInit.exe. Deleted local database file. Re-Ran DSInit.exe (which failed this time). Restored the local database file. It worked again. Rebooted computer. Started emulator. It doesn't work again. :(

**Update 2:** Ran DSInit.exe /forcecreate again. It works again.

**Update 3:** Rebooted. Problem is back.

Comment: 'The remote server returned an error: NotFound.' may be a certificate problem

Comment: How do you fix a certificate problem?